# when does ':' show up in function arguments / keyword arguments in python?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I've been coding in python for quite a while but I came across a piece of code which got me really confused, as I've never seen expressions like this before:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, config:dict, pool_args: dict=None, background: bool=True, **kwargs):
         self._config = config
         self._pool_args = pool_args
          ...
```

so what is this type of syntax: `config:dict` and `pool_args: dict=None` inside the function argument brackets?
   Are they used often?  I've really never seen this before.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html This provides more details

Answer (score 1):

These are type hints. See this for more details: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/